# Copy range of column based on number

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to copy group of columns into next available column base on number.
For example:

TemplateSheet: A|B|C|D, like to copy the content into another sheet, continuous add based on group number.

```
NoOfgroups = 4

For aGroup = 0 To sNoOfgroups:
    Worksheets("TemplateSheet").Range("A:D").Copy
    Worksheets("Row1").Range("A:D").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Worksheets("Row1").Select

Next
```

How to copy the A:D to next set, like E:H, then I:L,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy With Column Offset

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyOffset()

    Const NoOfgroups As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.Worksheets("TemplateSheet").Range("A:D")
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = wb.Worksheets("Row1").Range("A1")
    
    Dim aGroup As Long
    
    For aGroup = 1 To NoOfgroups
        srg.Copy dfCell
        Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(, scCount)
    Next aGroup

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your time, I will need to understand what is happening and how to execute the CopyOffset function. There are other pieces that I'm adding. First is to copy the template depending how many time it needs to loop. Then, Adding the strings into cells. As I'm using the mapping fill the cell. I was wondering if I can provide the code, can you review it?